# socket io not emitting message to particular socket after updating node js to 1.0.6

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am facing issues emitting message to a particular socket
after updating socket to 1.0.6
my this code : `io.sockets.socket(socks[sendallto]).emit('message',data);`

where socket[sendallto] is the socket id where I want to send message
was working fine before updating socket io
it was working in 0.9.16
any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: `io.sockets.socket`? Shouldn't it be `io.sockets(socks[sendallto])...`?

Comment: @Houseman it gives me error like property sockets of object io is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code should do the trick:

```
io.to(socks[sendallto]).emit('message',data);
```

By the way, you updated Socket.IO library, not Node.js. The latest stable Node.js version is [0.10.29](http://nodejs.org/) :D

Comment: that helped @CuriousGuy !! you were write about node. It was socket that i updated not node. I corrected it..